# ios.statusbar_hidden issue with Codenameone on Netbeans

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to set ios.statusbar_hidden as true in build hints in CodenameOne.
I am using Netbeans.
However, after I apply the change, it automatically resets it to false.
The build sent for IOS also seems to have this property set to false as the status bar is not hidden and shows up on the form title bar.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was deprecated by Apple and is meaningless as of iOS 7. You should use:

```
 ios.plistInject=<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key><true/><key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key><false/>
```